# What is the most common method of provisioning users in Exchange and Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, exchange

I'm developing a tool that is intended to be used as part of provisioning new users/mailboxes within an organization. I've read that it's not really possible to add hooks to AD for new user creation ([How can I run a python script when a new user is created in Active Directory?](https://serverfault.com/questions/187268/how-can-i-run-a-python-script-when-a-new-user-is-created-in-active-directory)), and that it's probably better to have my tool be executed as part of the general workflow used by an organization ([User Creation "Event" to run a Script](https://serverfault.com/q/350390/228108)).

Since I'm not targeting any particular organization, I want to provide a solution that will be useful to the largest group of AD/Exchange admins. What is the most common method of adding new users/mailboxes within an organization running Exchange+AD? A PowerShell script running `New-Mailbox`? A GUI interface?

My current plan is to provide a PowerShell script (or Cmdlet?) that can be invoked within an existing PowerShell workflow for creating new mailboxes.

Comment: I'd love to know what *new* problem you think you're solving here. Provisioning AD and Exchange users is well understood, and the "market" is saturated with different solutions. If you're trying to solve this issue for a large number of organisations, you'll need to make sure you can work with multiple-domain forests, multiple UPNs, Azure AD and Exchange Online mailboxes (which also means assigning Office 365 licences). Using the standard Powershell tools is probably your best bet, I can't think of many people who would want to "add hooks" to AD to solve an already solved problem.

Comment: The tool itself is entirely unrelated to AD/Exchange, however I'm targeting Exchange because my tool is related to email and Exchange is ubiquitous. I'm solving the problem of automatically publishing DANE SMIMEA records for email addresses within an organization, the keyword being *automatically*, which something that has never been solved.

Comment: @joe It looks like you have a XY problem here. You need to auto-publish records in DNS while asking how to create new mailboxes and AD users.

Answer (score 1):

When using AD, Powershell is the bees knees. I'd definitely recommend it. We use it heavily in our organization.